# How do I configure Read the Docs to use sphinx-autodoc-annotation?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I'm using [sphinx-autodoc-annotation](https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-autodoc-annotation/) to read the function annotations in my Python code and use that to generate the appropriate expected argument types and return types. It's working great on my local machine, but I had to `pip install sphinx-autodoc-annotation` of course.

I'm trying to generate the same documentation using [Read the Docs](https://readthedocs.org/), but it gives me an error:

```
Could not import extension sphinx_autodoc_annotation (exception: No module named sphinx_autodoc_annotation)
```

Is it possible to configure Read the Docs to work with sphinx-autodoc-annotation, and if so, how do I make it work?

Answer (score 2):

I don't like having a bunch of documentation requirements packaged through `setup.py`, so my recommendation is not to use the **Install Project** option on RTD. Instead, I prefer put a custom `requirements.txt` in my `doc/` folder, and point RTD to it:

[image]

Stick whatever you have in `setup.py`'s `install_requires` and/or `requirements.txt` into this file. Make sure that any additional sphinx extensions you are using are in there as well.

That should take care of all your dependencies. The other interesting settings I would recommend look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Activate the *Install Project* option for your Read the Docs project.

If the option is activated, Read the Docs will try to execute `setup.py install` on your package (see: [RtD docs](https://read-the-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/builds.html#understanding-what-s-going-on)). In `setup.py`, you can install packages as specified in your [requirements file](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/1.1/requirements.html).
Have a look at the [source code of the Flask-MongoRest project](https://github.com/closeio/flask-mongorest) for an example.

Add `sphinx-autodoc-annotation` as the only requirement to your `requirements.txt` file.

Comment: This is close, but isn't completely working yet. I added `requirements.txt` to the `docs` folder (since it's only needed to build the docs, not the project itself), pointed to that in the RtD settings, turned on "Install your project inside a virtualenv using setup.py install". I don't get errors, but now it's failing to create the `py-modindex.html` file, which it creates when I run Sphinx locally. I think that I need to post the question with all these additional details.