# How to get Read the Docs to generate py-modindex.html?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I'm trying to get Read the Docs to generate the `py-modindex.html` file. Research into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187770/how-do-i-configure-read-the-docs-to-use-sphinx-autodoc-annotation/) lead me to the following setup:

- `setup.py` in the project directory has the following contents, which were the minimum needed to get `pytest` to work and haven't been changed since I got that part of my project working:

  ```
  import setuptools

  setuptools.setup(
      name='polygons',
      packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
  )
  ```
- `docs/requirements.txt` contains a single line:

  ```
  sphinx-autodoc-annotation
  ```
- The Read the Docs repository URL points to my [GitHub](https://github.com/chivalry/polygons) repository.
- The RtD setting for "Install your project inside a virtualenv using setup.py install" is checked.
- The RtD setting for "Requirements file" points to `docs/requirements.txt`.

The "Module Index" link gets included in [`index.html`](http://polygons.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but the `py-modindex.html` file is missing.

My understanding is that with the virtualenv setting above, RtD will use the `setup.py` file to install the project so that Sphinx can read the documentation found in the Python docstrings. I'm using function annotations and would like `sphyinx-autodoc-annotation` to make use of those when creating the built docs files. All of this works splendidly on my local machine when I run `make html` while in the `docs` folder. Now I'm trying to get it to work on Read the Docs.

> Note: This is an exercise I'm going through to understand everything before I apply it to my real project, which the polygons project is a placeholder for.